# Using redis in front of MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql, redis

We have a mysql database of size 4TB. It has around 3000 tables with few tables having size of 200-300GB. 
Sometimes queries takes longer than 60 to 100 seconds on these bigger tables.

A Java application loads data into this database. Another Java spring based web application searches this database..so only select queries are used by this web application.

I am planning to use redis database in between web application and MySQL to improve the select query and in turn web application performance.

Planning to do one time migration to redis initially and then edit Java application to insert data into both MySQL and redis.

Can I use redis for this use case? Please let me know if there are any other ideas.
As per MySQL DBA, it is tuned to maximum extent.

We can't do much changes at database side due to infrastructure challenges. I can try only Software related changes

Comment: Better ask on StackOverflow. My experience with Java code and DB queries is that these are often generated by frameworks and even if the are often good, they are rarely optimal (and there are a couple of pathological cases).

Comment: This question is too broad and conflates tasks. It probably should have been migrated to [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), where you can discuss concepts and design. Divide your problem into (1) the Redis installation and configuration; and (2) whatever code you write for Redis. Ask question (1) somewhere else; ask question (2) here. Stack Overflow cannot help with (2) until you have a real, concrete problems. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Redis is good to 'cache' data. It doesn't replace a DBMS and its complex query language. Your question is indeed too broad - and MySQL does also some caching itself, for repeated queries. A minute to reply a query seems long ; but maybe you have some indexes issues in the first place...  But that depends on so many factors ; without more details, it's hard to give a direction to go to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which data model in your web application.
you can choose Memcached if it just about just k/v load, otherwise you can choose Redis.